# Is there any way to use both SQL and NO-SQL databases together in Django?

Tags: django, mongodb

I already have SQLite DB integrated with my web app (using Django web framework) but now I want to add MongoDB for NO-SQL component. Is there any way to use both SQL and NO-SQL together?

Answer (score 0):

Django Models only work with relational databases.  There is a GitHub project that was meant to be a MongoDB replacement for Django Model backend, but it is no longer maintained.  But there is nothing stopping you from putting python code that carries out CRUD operations with a NO-SQL database server in your Django project.  It's just that things like `makemigrations` and `migrate` will not work with your NO-SQL DB.